# What is the file structure of Neovim?

Tags: neovim, filesystem

It seems like Neovim has files in many places.

The binary is in `/usr/bin/nvim`.

Inside `~/.config/nvim` is `init.vim`, for declaring plugins, and also directories in `~/.config` for storing Neovim plugins, such as `coc`.

There is also an nvim directory in `~/.local/share`, including directories like `site/autoload`, for apparently “scripts you source before anything else which you can use in your .vimrc”.

It also seems like Neovim allows you to have a `.vimrc` file in your home directory.

What is every directory in your system that Neovim uses or creates, and what is its function?

Comment: At least read `:help runtimepath`; that should cover the major directories you’re likely to come across. Then there’s a variety of options whose values are directories (so they would influence that).